# New fulfillment Method not visible on storefront website

Tags: sitecore-commerce

**Sitecore XC: 9.3**

We are trying to create a new fulfilment method named *3-days delivery* under the `Ship Items` option (`/Sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Shared Settings/Fulfillment Options/Ship items`).

We have followed all the steps mentioned in the official [doc](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/walkthrough--configuring-fulfillment-options.html):

1. Created a new fulfilment method:
   [image]
2. Created a commerce term:
   [image]
3. Published the site and perform an IIS reset, still new shipping method not visible on the website.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this working, if anyone else stuck on this, they can follow the below steps to resolve this issue:

1. **Sync content items**: When you add a new Commerce content item or make changes to an existing one in the Commerce Control Panel (in the Sitecore Content Editor), you must synchronize the content item (defined in the Sitecore Content Editor) with the data in the Commerce Engine database. Refer to this [doc](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/synchronize-content-items.html).
2. Restart IIS and Commerce Engine instances.
3. You must flush the Redis cache (use the `flushall` command in Redis).

After following the above steps, you can check fulfilment options using `Get all fulfillment methods` Postman API requests:

```
{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/GetFulfillmentMethods()
```